# can an angular directive provide a public method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to Angular, and it's very possible that the answer to my question will be "that's not how it's done in angular".

I have a template-expanding directive that presents a checklist:

```
[ ] mushrooms
[ ] peppers
[ ] onions
[ ] artichokes
[ ] anchovies
```

The dataSource for the checklist is an array of objects.  One of the properties of the underlying object is "bits":

```
mushrooms  bits:2, 
peppers bits: 4, 
onions bits: 8, 
artichokes bits: 16, 
anchovies: 32.
```

Someone who orders a pizza with mushrooms and anchovies would have total bits: 34.

Is there a way for the checklist directive to encapsulate a `TotalBits()` method that would be accessible to the $scope? Is there a "handle" to the instantiated checklist object in $scope?

Comment: You typically pass the checkList as argument to the directive, and the directive modifies it. Since you created and passed the checkList, you can access its attributes. Just like you pass the model using ng-model to an input directive.

Comment: My directive creates the HTML that produces the checkbox items. But I don't understand how, in my directive code, to "embed" a TotalBits() function, and then how to expose the return value of the function in a way that it could be bound to another scope variable. Ultimately, I want to save the total-bits value to the database. I can have a *separate* function to calculate the total bits, but I'm wondering it that function can be encapsulated in the checklist directive.

Comment: How do I refer to the checklist as an entity?  It has a container div. It consists of p elements. check inputs and labels.

Comment: You can add as many functions you want to the directive's scope, and these functions could update the checkList model that you pass as argument to the directive.

Answer (score 0):

You could always pass a callback method to the directive (as a an attribute) which will be called by the directive once it has the number of bits calculated.

Comment: How would the return value of the `TotalBits()` method get bound to `$scope.pizzaBits`?

Comment: You pass the method "onTotalBitsCalculated" from what I assume is the controller as an attribute to the directive. Inside the directive, once a selection has been determined, you invoke the onTotalBitsCalculated method with the totalBits value. Inside the controller, the onTotalBitsCalculated method that was passed to the directive will look something like this:



onTotalBitsCalculated = function (totalBits) {
$scope.pizzaBits = totalBits; }

Comment: So the directive cannot be a "self-contained" object with its own properties and its own methods?  That function must be *passed* to it?

Comment: Well, if you want different scopes (i.e controllers) to have access to that value generated by the directive and handle it in a different manner in each controller, I don't see another way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your module to achieve this functionality. See this example:

```
var menu = [{
    name: 'mushrooms',
    bits: 2,
    selected: false
}, {
    name: 'pepers',
    bits: 4,
    selected: false
}];
menu.totalBits = function () {
    var total = 0;
    this.forEach(function (item) {
        if (item.selected) total = total + item.bits;
    });
    return total;
};
```

Since JS is malleable, we can add totalBits function to the model array and thats it.

I created a fiddle for it too http://jsfiddle.net/s8n5y2kg/

Comment: Thank you for answering. That is the approach I am taking (but using standard loop). But I was wondering more about the capabilities of directives, and if that functionality could somehow be encapsulated in the checklist "control", so that the control's totalBits value could be bound to a scalar variable in the form's model.